# MYSQL не хочет создвать таблицу с названием, в котором есть пробел

Tags: mysql

При создании таблицы (название которой идет вместе с заголовком и контентом через форму) почему-то возникает ошибка, если в названии таблицы - два слова через пробел.

выдает ошибку:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'gdfg (id INT (11)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,title VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT 0 ,cont' at line 1""

где "gdfg" — это второе слово в названии таблицы. с одним словом в названии проблем нет, а вот если в названии два слова - возникает ошибка.

код создания выглядит так:

```
$comand="CREATE TABLE $category_ (id INT (11)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,title VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT 0 ,content VARCHAR(4096) NULL DEFAULT 0,
    data TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,PRIMARY KEY (id))";
    mysql_query($comand)or die(mysql_error());
    $comand="INSERT INTO $category_ (title, content) VALUES ('$titles','$contents')";
    mysql_query($comand)or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 4):

> Так как пробелы используются для разделения частей команды SQL,  они
>    не могут быть частью имени таблицы ( или любого другого объекта, такого как индекс ).  Подчеркивание ( _ ) - обычно используется для разделения слов в именах таблиц.

Можно задавать имя таблицы с пробелом, но только в апострофах(в кавычках нельзя). Также зависит от версии Mysql.

Comment: Где вы такую документацию нашли, только что проверял, отлично создаются таблицы с пробелами (в апострофах конечно)

Comment: @Mike пересмотрел доки на последние версии, действительно можно, но только в апострофах, но не понял с какой версии начиная. Раньше вообще нельзя было.

Answer (score 4):

Если вы хотите создать таблицу с пробелом в имени, то ее имя надо заключать в обратные апострофы:

```
create table `abc def` (id int not null)
```

Но вам так же придется при любом упоминании ее имени в любых SQL запросах так же заключать ее в обратные апострофы.